# Reasons for not having domain model relations in db?

Tags: database-design, domain-driven-design

Are there scenarios where one might not want to persist relations between domain models in a database?

I was recently in a conversation where the designer was justifying his approach by saying that from security perspective certain relationships should be navigable to a given user, hence he is not in favour of having those relations explicitly defined in db/entity models.

Are there other standard ways of addressing that concern? Are there other well-known scenarios where one might not want to persist relationships?

Comment: The database is for storing and maintaining the integrity of data. If relationships are required to achieve this goal, use them. You must not allow your domain to govern how your database is structured, just as you must not allow your database to dictate your domain design. The influence of one on the other is unavoidable, but keep it to a minimum as their purposes differ. The difficulty then lies around the way to bridge the disconnects between the domain and the database, but at least they will be robust individually.

Comment: This doesn't make sense on the face of it: if a relationship isn't persisted, how will you retrieve related data?

Comment: @Dave the idea here was not to have the relationship expressed as an aggregation between the domain models e.g considering Employee and Department as 2 models Employee.getDepartment() will not return the Department model as expected, and thus expressing the relationship that further can be persisted as such in a db. The proposal is to model the relationship through another class called Dependency. Employee.getDepartment() just returns the departmentId string that can be used to lookup.

Comment: @redzedi, this borders on re-inventing the relational database. As I suggested, use the database as it was designed for and build a rich domain domain. The correctness that you will achieve in each far outweighs the cost of integration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a means to work around having an improperly-modeled database and/or application. A user has no direct access to their department unless the application specifically allows it/displays it.

Navigation to data, and queries that retrieve data, should be two different things (IMO), even in DDD. Doing role-based access by removing natural relationships seems backwards.

In addition, there is a speed penalty paid for not being able to do joins at the DB level, instead relegating them to an ad-hoc "join" at the application code level, which would seem to complicate things